# Which label from different points inside a polygon is the most repeated

Tags: labeling, buffer, point

I have millions of points, each point with a label. These points are inside of different buffers (polygons). I want to create a new column that puts the value of the label that is repeated more time inside of a polygon. I draw something just to give you an idea. The circles are the buffers, and the labels of each point are 1,2,3 in the buffer on top left I gave it the label 2 because we see two points with that label.

[image]

Comment: What software and license level are you running?

Comment: I am using ArcMap 10.3.1 and I have around 6 000 000 of polygons. At the end I need a csv file with the new column, so if somebody knows about other program that could also help me

Comment: Just a rough sketch how you could do it: Use `select by location` on the point layer for each polygon you have, count the points based on their attributes and attach the highest scoring attribute to the polygon. Repeat for the next polygon, using pyhton most likely. Possible problem: Similar amount of points of one number within one polygon.

Comment: If you are running an Advanced license, you can use the Intersect tool with the points and polygons to assign a polygon ID to each point. Then use the  Frequency tool to see which labels are showing up the most in each polygon.  You need an Advanced license to use Frequency.